# how to change footer content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I want my output to be:- copyright@shravansoft2015
at present its showing me as copyrightsshravansoft2015
my footer code is as follows

footer.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Footer.php outputs the code for your footer widgets, contains your footer hook and closing body/html tags
 * @package Tetris WordPress Theme
 * @since 1.0
 * @author AJ Clarke : http://wpexplorer.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2012, AJ Clarke
 * @link http://wpexplorer.com
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 */
?>
<div class="clear">`enter code here`</div><!-- /clear any floats -->    
</div><!-- /main-content -->

    <div id="footer-wrap">

        <footer id="footer">

            <div id="footer-widgets" class="clearfix">

                <div class="footer-box">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-one'); ?>

                </div><!-- /footer-box -->

                <div class="footer-box">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-two'); ?>

                </div><!-- /footer-box -->

                <div class="footer-box remove-margin">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-three'); ?>
                </div><!-- /footer-box -->

            </div><!-- /footer-widgets -->
        </footer><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /footer-wrap -->

    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wpex_copyright', '1' ) ) { ?>

        <div id="copyright">

            <?php echo get_theme_mod('wpex_copyright', 'Powered by 

<a href=\"http://www.wordpress.org\" title="WordPress" 

target="_blank">WordPress</a> and <a 

href=\"http://themeforest.net/user/WPExplorer?ref=WPExplorer" target="_blank" 

title="WPExplorer" rel="nofollow">WPExplorer Themes</a>') ?>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

</div><!-- /wrap -->

<?php wp_footer(); // Footer hook, do not delete, ever ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line: `<?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wpex_copyright', '1' ) ) { ?>`

This area is controlled by your theme. To change this you'll need to visit 
the Wordpress dashboard and select **Appearance > Customize**. From the customizer menu you'll select "Theme Settings".

> I want my output to be:- copyright@shravansoft2015 at present its showing me as copyrightsshravansoft2015

I'm not sure why the @ symbol would be removed. If you add `<p>copyright@shravansoft2015</p>` to the "Custom Copyright" area, it should work fine.

[image: customizer screenshot]